# How can show multiple data on hover with highmaps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, highcharts

How can show multipe datas on hover on map with highmaps?

http://www.highcharts.com/maps/demo

Normally we can show data like this:

```
 var data = [];
    $.each(columns[0], function (i, code) {
        data.push({
            code: code,
            value: columns[3][i],
            name: columns[2][i],
            hasta:columns[4][i]

        });
    });
```

But this allow only one type data with joinBy:

```
 series : [{
                    data : data,
                    mapData: Highcharts.maps['countries/tr/tr-all'],
                    joinBy: ['hc-key','name'],
                    animation: true,
                    name: 'Diyaliz Verileri',
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            color: '#BADA55'
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        valueSuffix: ''
                    }
                }]
```

But When we want to show multple datas on hover , What we can do?

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/CMengineer/j9mujnnz/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works the same as a regular highcharts graph.  Just define a customer tooltip [formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter):

```
             tooltip: {
                 formatter: function(){
                     var s = this.key + '<br/>';
                     s += 'Value:' + this.point.value + '<br/>';
                     s += 'Hasta:' + this.point.hasta;
                     return s;
                 },
             },
```

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j9mujnnz/1/).

Comment: not working for me ;( in your jsfiddle example the formatter function is very different